# Applying an ITIN (W7 form) for my F2 spouse to claim an exemption

Tags: united-states, irs, non-resident, itin

I am on F1 visa, Non-resident alien, F2 visa spouse claimed for expemtion on basis of Indo-US tax treaty.

Which option should I choose on W7 for the section "Reason You’re Submitting Form W-7"
a) Nonresident alien required to get an ITIN to claim tax
treaty benefit.
OR
g) Dependent/spouse of a nonresident alien holding a U.S.
visa

my agent says option 'a' since we are claiming exemption under treaty.
but from the IRS document I feel its option 'g' because it makes more sense.